# ActiveSupport::Callbacks - Memory Leak

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks, ruby-on-rails-5

I am debugging a memory leak and dig out some interesting things. Need input from you guys weather its a memory leak or something else.

So first here is the script I run to verify blank state:

```
require 'objspace'
ObjectSpace.trace_object_allocations_start

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'production'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
GC.start
heap_values = GC::stat[:heap_live_slots]
ObjectSpace.dump_all output: 'start.dump'

# Processing Code
10_000_00.times do 
   a = 'Some random string'
end

GC.start
heap_values2 = GC::stat[:heap_live_slots]
ObjectSpace.dump_all output: 'end.dump'

puts heap_values2 - heap_values
```

When I run above script I usually get `0` or a `negative` output. Which seems obvious and clearly shows no memory leak.

No if I replace my processing code with some real active record queries and different json processing. The output difference of heap slots return a `high number`. In my code normally over 1k objects.

To dig further I compare both heap dumps and tried to identify which objects are available in heap at the end of script, which were not available in start.

I used the script https://gist.github.com/nazarhussain/e2f95518cc7e236afbbb501f1e00fbe4 to compare two heap dumps.

Most of the retained objects in memory are of type DATA and coming from
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L382
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L385

Can any one help me to further diagnose. Does the difference in heap slots can really be considered as memory leaks? Why those proc from callbacks retained in memory even after end of script and GC.start?